# тег текста находится в неправильном блоке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Приветствую всех заглянувших. У меня есть небольшая проблема, тег текста находится не там где нужно. Элемент касается середины слайдера, а я хочу, чтобы он находился после остальных тегов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде попытался что-то сделать,но не получилось. И еще, хотелось бы сделать адаптивный `header`, он не растягивается на 100 процентов экрана, если уменьшить окно, то блок не будет задевать края.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #515151;
}


/*Header with Spread logo, and links...*/

.font-face {
  font-family: Tolkien;
  src: url(Tolky.TTF);
}

a {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none
}

header {
  min-height: 9vh;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  font-family: Tolkien;
  src: url(Tolky.TTF);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header_logo_links {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

.margin_0_and_logo {
  display: contents;
}

.spread_logotype {
  font-size: 3em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.spread_text {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.header_links {
  font-family: Radwave;
  src: url(RadwaveFont-Regular.otf);
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-top: 0.33em;
  display: flex;
}

.link_text {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 1em;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.link_text:hover {
  color: lawngreen;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
}


/*Slaider for third images*/

.all {
  height: 45vh;
}

slider {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 10px;
}

#slider {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#slides article {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

#slides .image {
  width: 500%;
  line-height: 0;
}

#overflow {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article img {
  width: 100%;
}

#switch2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1),
#switch3:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
#switch5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(4) {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/abBxfpM.png) no-repeat;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
}

#switch1:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
#switch2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(3),
#switch5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1) {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/dggILEN.png) no-repeat;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  height: 68px;
  width: 68px;
}

label,
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.all input {
  display: none;
}

#switch1:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#switch2:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#switch3:checked~#slides .image {
  margin-left: -200%;
}

#controls {
  margin: -47vh 0px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

#active label {
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #bbb;
}

#active label:hover {
  background: #76c8ff;
  border-color: #777 !important;
}

#slides .image {
  transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

#controls label:hover {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#controls label {
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
}

a#download {
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header_logo_links">
    <div class="spread_logotype">
      <div class="margin_0_and_logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/h8wzsPB.png" alt="Пример"></a>
        <a href="index.html" class="spread_text">pread</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header_links">
      <a href="#" class="link_text">Merch</a>
      <a href="#" class="link_text">Music</a>
      <a href="#" class="link_text">Videos</a>
      <a href="#" class="link_text">Community</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<section>
  <div class="all">
    <input checked type="radio" name="respond" id="desktop">
    <article id="slider">
      <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="switch1">
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch2">
      <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch3">
      <div id="slides">
        <div id="overflow">
          <div class="image">
            <article><img src="https://i.imgur.com/AUb3z25.png"></article>
            <article><img src="https://i.imgur.com/JYym5Ua.png"></article>
            <article><img src="https://i.imgur.com/sSc1w0l.png"></article>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="controls">
        <label for="switch1"></label>
        <label for="switch2"></label>
        <label for="switch3"></label>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</section>
<h1>434</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел пока такое решение проблемы. Я задал `section`'у класс и указал в нем общие размеры блока со слайдером изображений:

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #515151;
    }


    /*Header with Spread logo, and links...*/

    .font-face {
      font-family: Tolkien;
      src: url(Tolky.TTF);
    }

    a {
      color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      text-decoration: none
    }

    header {
      min-height: 9vh;
      background-color: #1b1b1b;
      font-family: Tolkien;
      src: url(Tolky.TTF);
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1000em;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .header_logo_links {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .margin_0_and_logo {
      display: contents;
    }

    .spread_logotype {
      font-size: 3em;
      display: flex;
      align-items: baseline;
    }

    .spread_text {
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }

    .header_links {
      font-family: Radwave;
      src: url(RadwaveFont-Regular.otf);
      font-size: 1.5em;
      margin-top: 0.33em;
      display: flex;
    }

    .link_text {
      color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      padding: 1em;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
    }

    .link_text:hover {
      color: lawngreen;
      transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    }


    /*Slaider for third images*/

    .slaider__main{
      height: 80vh;
  }

    slider {
      position: relative;
      text-align: center;
      top: 10px;
    }

    #slider {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #slides article {
      width: 20%;
      float: left;
    }

    #slides .image {
      width: 500%;
      line-height: 0;
    }

    #overflow {
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    article img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    #switch2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1),
    #switch3:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
    #switch5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(4) {
      background: url(https://i.imgur.com/abBxfpM.png) no-repeat;
      float: left;
      display: block;
      height: 68px;
      width: 68px;
    }

    #switch1:checked~#controls label:nth-child(2),
    #switch2:checked~#controls label:nth-child(3),
    #switch5:checked~#controls label:nth-child(1) {
      background: url(https://i.imgur.com/dggILEN.png) no-repeat;
      float: right;
      display: block;
      height: 68px;
      width: 68px;
    }

    label,
    a {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .all input {
      display: none;
    }

    #switch1:checked~#slides .image {
      margin-left: 0;
    }

    #switch2:checked~#slides .image {
      margin-left: -100%;
    }

    #switch3:checked~#slides .image {
      margin-left: -200%;
    }

    #controls {
      margin: -47vh 0px 0px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
    }

    #active label {
      border-radius: 10px;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      background: #bbb;
    }

    #active label:hover {
      background: #76c8ff;
      border-color: #777 !important;
    }

    #slides .image {
      transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    }

    #controls label:hover {
      opacity: 0.6;
    }

    #controls label {
      transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
    }

    a#download {
      text-align: center;
      width: 150px;
      margin: 0px auto;
      padding: 20px;
      color: white;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: Arial;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="header_logo_links">
        <div class="spread_logotype">
          <div class="margin_0_and_logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/h8wzsPB.png" alt="Пример"></a>
            <a href="index.html" class="spread_text">pread</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header_links">
          <a href="#" class="link_text">Merch</a>
          <a href="#" class="link_text">Music</a>
          <a href="#" class="link_text">Videos</a>
          <a href="#" class="link_text">Community</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

     <section class="slaider__main">
      <div class="all">
        <input checked type="radio" name="respond" id="desktop">
        <article id="slider">
          <input checked type="radio" name="slider" id="switch1">
          <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch2">
          <input type="radio" name="slider" id="switch3">
          <div id="slides">
            <div id="overflow">
              <div class="image">
                <article><img src="https://i.imgur.com/AUb3z25.png"></article>
                <article><img src="https://i.imgur.com/JYym5Ua.png"></article>
                <article><img src="https://i.imgur.com/sSc1w0l.png"></article>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="controls">
            <label for="switch1"></label>
            <label for="switch2"></label>
            <label for="switch3"></label>
          </div>
        </article>
      </div>
    </section>
    <h1>434</h1>
```

Comment: Удалил из вашего ответа формулировки о дальнейшем улучшении. Вы дали ответ. На ответ обычно никто не отвечает. Если вы не уверены в своём ответе, то две возмоожности: 1) удалите этот ответ и дополните вопрос 2) задайте новый вопрос и сошлитесь на текущий как на взаимосвязанный.